# Image.getBitmap() returning null?

Tags: java, android, teechart

Consider this code:

```
Image img = chart.getExport().getImage().image(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

I would expect it to return the actual bitmap using this code:

```
img.getBitmap();
```

However, that returns null! How come I cannot retrieve the underlying bitmap? How is it generated?

Comment: Are you doing this in onCreate()?

Comment: What class is `chart`? Have you looked to see if there is anything in the documentation of whatever that is that might address this?

Comment: Tagged as `teechart`. Hence, it's a `TChart` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `bitmap` instead of `getBitmap()`. The following code seems to work fine for me here:

```
Bar bar = new Bar(tChart1.getChart());
bar.fillSampleValues();
bar.setColorEach(true);

tChart1.doInvalidate();
Image img = tChart1.getExport().getImage().image(400, 200);
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), img.bitmap, "test.jpg", "test.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks! Works, but still a bit odd :)